# GLSL Phong Shading not working

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting, phong

I am trying to use [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Smooth_Specular_Highlights) for per-fragment shading and adapt it to GLSL #version 140. The results I am getting are obviously not correct. Seems to me that I am doing something wrong with the supplied normals, since there is a direct change between light and shade on some triangles which are next to each other on the same plane.

[image]

The vertex shader code:

```
#version 140
in vec3 position;
in vec2 texIn;
in vec3 normal;

smooth out vec2 texCoor;
out vec4 v_position; // position of the vertex (and fragment) in world space
out vec3 NormalDirection;  // surface normal vector in world space

uniform mat4  mP, mV, mM;   // transformation matrices
uniform mat3 m_3x3_inv_transp;

void main() {
  v_position = mM * vec4(position, 1.0);
  NormalDirection = normalize(m_3x3_inv_transp * normal);

  mat4 mvp = mP*mV*mM;
  gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
  texCoor = texIn;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 140
uniform mat4 mM, mV, mP;
uniform mat4 mV_inv;
uniform sampler2D texSampler; // sampler for texture access

smooth in vec2 texCoor;    // from Vertex shader
in vec4 v_position; // position of the vertex (and fragment) in world space
in vec3 NormalDirection;  // surface normal vector in world space

out vec4 colorOut; // fragment color

struct lightSource {
  vec4 position;
  vec4 diffuse;
  vec4 specular;
  float constantAttenuation, linearAttenuation, quadraticAttenuation;
  float spotCutoff, spotExponent;
  vec3 spotDirection;
};
lightSource light0 = lightSource(
  vec4(5.0,  5.0,  5.0, 1.0),
  vec4(2.0,  2.0,  2.0, 1.0),
  vec4(2.0,  2.0,  2.0, 1.0),
  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
  180.0, 0.0,
  vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
);
vec4 scene_ambient = vec4(1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.0);

struct material {
  vec4 ambient;
  vec4 diffuse;
  vec4 specular;
  float shininess;
};
material frontMaterial = material(
  vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0),
  vec4(1.0, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0),
  vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  5.0
);

void main() {
  vec3 normalDirection = normalize(NormalDirection);
  vec3 viewDirection = normalize(vec3(mV_inv * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) - v_position));
  vec3 lightDirection;
  float attenuation;

  if (0.0 == light0.position.w) // directional light?
    {
      attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
      lightDirection = normalize(vec3(light0.position));
    } 
  else // point light or spotlight (or other kind of light) 
    {
      vec3 positionToLightSource = vec3(light0.position - v_position);
      float distance = length(positionToLightSource);
      lightDirection = normalize(positionToLightSource);
      attenuation = 1.0 / (light0.constantAttenuation
                           + light0.linearAttenuation * distance
                           + light0.quadraticAttenuation * distance * distance);

      if (light0.spotCutoff <= 90.0) // spotlight?
        {
          float clampedCosine = max(0.0, dot(-lightDirection, light0.spotDirection));
          if (clampedCosine < cos(radians(light0.spotCutoff))) // outside of spotlight cone?
            {
              attenuation = 0.0;
            }
          else
            {
              attenuation = attenuation * pow(clampedCosine, light0.spotExponent);   
            }
        }
    }

  vec3 ambientLighting = vec3(scene_ambient) * vec3(frontMaterial.ambient);

  vec3 diffuseReflection = attenuation 
    * vec3(light0.diffuse) * vec3(frontMaterial.diffuse)
    * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));

  vec3 specularReflection;
  if (dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0) // light source on the wrong side?
    {
      specularReflection = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // no specular reflection
        }
      else // light source on the right side
    {
      specularReflection = attenuation * vec3(light0.specular) * vec3(frontMaterial.specular) 
        * pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), viewDirection)), frontMaterial.shininess);
    }

  colorOut = vec4(ambientLighting + diffuseReflection + specularReflection, 1.0) *         texture(texSampler, texCoor);
}
```

C++ code (uniforms):

```
// matrices to vertex shader
  glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); // identity matrix - table is static
  glUniformMatrix4fv(locations.Mmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));

  glUniformMatrix4fv(locations.Pmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(locations.Vmatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));

  glm::mat3 m_inv_transp = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(modelMatrix)));
  glUniformMatrix3fv(locations.m_3x3_inv_transp, 1, GL_FALSE,     glm::value_ptr(m_inv_transp));

  glm::mat3 v_inv = glm::inverse(glm::mat3(viewMatrix));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(locations.Vmatrix_inv, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(v_inv));
```

Comment: If you think there's a problem with the normals, why don't you check by drawing them? (colorOut = normalDirection * vec3(0.5) +v vec3(0.5);)

Comment: Thanks, that is a handy tip :) It helped a lot. There really was only a wrong offset where I was taking normals from interleaved array. So there is nothing wrong with the shaders after all. Problem solved, shading looking great! Where do I mark the question as solved? Thank you.

Comment: @VojtaHejda Perhaps post your comment as an answer?